# Is there a reason for this language switching?

Tags: kill-bill, dialogue

During the various scenes that take place in Japan, the characters sometimes speak English and sometimes Japanese, sometimes even a line in English as a reply to a line in Japanese or vice versa.

It was made clear that The Bride can speak and understand Japanese, is there a reason they keep switching languages like that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Switching between languages is a trick which gives a sense of authenticity to the movie, without having to translate the entire film.

There are actually three ways to manage different languages in a movie:

1. Using only one language and making the foreigners speaks with a different accent
2. Using every language when required, adding subtitles to the foreign languages
3. Switching between the main language and the foreign one

You can see the same stratagem on other Tarantino movies (e.g. *Inglorious Bastards*) and on other classics involving mixed cultures (e.g. "The Godfather").

Comment: ...or 4. Using only one language, with actors using their own accents (e.g. Valyrie).